# Logica Programacion

Tags: algoritmos

necesito si me pueden ayudar con un algoritmo sencillo en el lenguaje que sea,
tengo lo siguiente tengo un `existencia=3`, tengo un dos filas que tienen `saldo=1`, `saldo=3`, `precio_uni=154.16`, `precio_uni=116`.

bien lo que tengo que hacer es recorro `saldo` que tienen 1 y como no es igual a `existencia` paso los `154.16` de `precio`, entonces paso el segundo `saldo` que tiene 3 pero para a igualar las 3 de `existencia` solo ocupo 2 de `saldo` y subo los `precio` quería sumar dos veces 116 para que me diera 154.16+116+116 y así ya igualo los `saldos` con la `existencia`

Si alguien me puede ayudar con la lógica

Comment: Bro, la verdad no se te entiende que necesitas...

Comment: Haz un diagrama de lo que tienes y agrega lo que quieres mediante un ejemplo adicional que el mostrado, tampoco lo entiendo.

Comment: @srJJ deja me ver si me explico mas,  tengo existencia=3, que tiene saldo=1 (precio154.16), saldo= 3 (precio116) tengo que igualar los saldos con la existencia para que me quede un precio sumado 154.16+116+116 porque dos veces 116? porque ya tengo saldo 1 para acompletar lo mismo de existencia pido dos del segundo saldo para tenner misma existencia y la suma de los saldo me iguala la existencia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tratando de entender los que me dices creo que necesitas esto:

```
//el lenguaje es php
<?php
$existencia=3;
$saldo1= 1;
$precio1=154.16;
$saldo2= 3;
$precio2=116;



//corremos hasta saldo mayor
for (j=0; j < $saldo2;j++) 
{
//vamos a sumar si el es menor o igual a la existencia
    if ($saldo1 <= $existencia) {
        $saldo1 = $saldo1 + 1;
        $precio1 = $precio1 + $precio2;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: siii amigo asi mero, solo que tengo aparte de ese saldo=1 tengo otro que dice saldo=3 y con precio=116, va ahi con los datos que pusiste mas lo que te digo tengo que acompletar que me de la suma de los dos saldos me den lo mismo que en existencia si sobre pasa porque tengo 1+3 de saldo tengo restar no, entonces al ahora de restar sumaria en precios 154.16+116+116 me debe dar 386.16, no se si me explico trato de hacerlo

Comment: pero no entiendo que se debe haacer con los saldos? se deben sumar hasta que sean igual a existencia ? y cuando pase a ser mayor que ?

Comment: si amigo se deben sumar hasta que sea igual a existencia cuando ya sea a mayor no debo hacer nada solo debe quedar el resultado final que me interesa es que precio va quedar 154.16+116+116

Comment: mira ahi edite la respuesta la cual solo sumara hasta que `$saldo1` sea igual a  `$existencia`

Comment: Creo que eso es lo que necesitas...

Comment: @JavierSolis si era asi ?

Comment: Hola buen día si me sirvió muchísimo lo marco como solución muchas gracias quería ver la lógica para implantarlo en mi código real!!!

Comment: Me alegro mucho bro, exitos! ReNiceCode....

Answer (score 0):

Creo esto es lo que necesitas:

```
$existencia = 3;
$saldo1 = 1;
$saldo2 = 5;
$total = 0;

$precio1 = 154.16;
$precio2 = 116;

for($i=$saldo1; $i <= $saldo2; $i++){
    if($i > $existencia){
        break;
    }
    $total = ($i==$saldo1) ? $total + $precio1 : $total + $precio2;

}
echo "Total: ". $total;
```

Ver [DEMO](https://ideone.com/7pLyYn)

Alli estamos iniciando el bucle con saldo 1 mientras este sea menos o igual a saldo 2, Luego validamos que si $i es igual al saldo 1, sume el precio uno, en caso contrario que sume el precio 2 tantas veces como le reste al bucle y como ya consumimos el saldo 1, solo nos quedan dos vueltas para igualar la existencia por lo que se sumarían 116 dos veces al total

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvio tambien